# Grouping in Linq queries with multiple tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the two tables

```
Person
__________
PersonID
PersonName
DOB
Status


Notes
__________
NoteID
PersonID
NoteText
Comments
LineNo
```

here is some sample content

```
 PersonID   PersonName    DOB          Status
   1        Mark Jacobs   07/07/1961    Active
```

and

```
NoteID  PersonID    NoteText    LineNo
 123       1        Line 1      1
 234       1        Line 2      2
 236       1        Line 3      3
```

So as an end result I want a Linq query to display something like that

```
PersonID    PersonName    DOB           Note
   1        Mark Jacobs   07/07/1961    Line 1
                                        Line 2
                                        Line 3
```

All the examples I found so far only have one table, so I tried to start with grouping just the Notes table as follows:

```
var result = (from n in db.Notes
              group n.NoteText by n.PersonID into g
              select new NoteGrp { 
                  PersonID = g.Key, 
                  Notes = g.ToList().ToString() 
              }).AsEnumerable();
```

in the function it is something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<NoteGrp> GetNotes()
{
    using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {               
        var result = (from n in db.Notes
                      group n.NoteText by n.PersonID into g
                     select new NoteGrp { PersonID = g.Key, Note = g.ToList().ToString() }).AsEnumerable();
        return result;
    }
}
```

It compiles fine and does error out until it gets to return result. If I view result object in the watch window and expand it to voew the results, I see `The entity or complex type 'NoteGrp' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query` inner exception.
But if I let it run through then in the browser I get the following: `The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'text/html;`

P.S. `NoteGrp` is a class I created that contains only 2 members: PersonID as an int and Notes as a string

```
public class NoteGrp
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

    }
```

I also tried using

```
 var result = db.Notes.GroupBy(n => new { n.PersonID }).Select(g => new NoteGrp{PersonID= g.Key.personID, Notes = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.NoteText)) }).ToList();
```

and got the same error that the entity of complex type cannot be constructed. I could use anonymous type:

```
var result = db.Notes.GroupBy(n => new { n.PersonID }).Select(g => new {PersonID= g.Key.personID, Notes = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.NoteText)) }).ToList();
```

but then I am not sure what return type should my function have...

Comment: Please show definition of `NoteGrp`

Comment: Added the NoteGrp

Comment: are person and note related via primary and foreign key relationship? if so, its pretty straight forward: db.Persons.Include(p => p.Notes).Select(p => new NoteGrp{ }); I did not check the syntax. But this should give you idea.

Comment: Why don't you put a collection of Notes on the Person class and EF will populate it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I assume (by it failing with this error but working with an anonymous type) the `NoteGrp` class is mapped and you can't instantiate an EF mapped object in a query. Create a DTO class (or an anonymous type Instead).

Also the use of `.ToList().ToString()` is probably not what you are looking for but what you want is `string.Join`:

```
public IEnumerable<NoteGrp> GetNotes()
{
    using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {
        var result = (from n in db.Notes
                      group n.NoteText by n.PersonID into g
                      select new { //Creating anonymous object with only the needed information
                          PersonID = g.Key, 
                          Notes = g.ToList()
                      }).AsEnumerable() //Bringing items to memory so can use string.Join
                     .Select(item => new NoteGroupDTO { //Instantiating new DTO object
                         PersonID = item.PersonID,
                         Notes = string.Join(", ", item.Notes)
                     }).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

class:

```
public class NoteGroupDTO
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: NoteGrp class is not mapped, just a class I created

Comment: I tried that and got the same old `The entity or complex type 'NoteGrp' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

Comment: @ElenaDBA - Then what is the `[Key]` attribute is for? remove it and try

Comment: if I remove `Key` attribute it says: `EntityType 'NoteGrpl' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType`

Comment: @ElenaDBA If this class is not mapped then why does it need `[Key]`? Where does it give you the error of `key not specified`?

Comment: The class is not connected to any tables. Could the issue be that it is inside the Model class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127293/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-elenadba).

Comment: @ElenaDBA - Check the chat

Comment: Yes!!! It worked! You just forgot keyword `new` after select. Now could you help me add another table - person table into the mix, as I need to display some fields from that table as well. I will open another question and would really appreciate your help!

Comment: @ElenaDBA - corrected :) and sure - post another one and you can comment me so I will see it :)

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406287/adding-another-table-to-a-grouped-linq-query  I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AsEnumerable` to change to *Linq to Objects* before the projection (`Select`) to avoid *Linq to Entities* limitations like `String.Join`:

```
var result = db.Notes.GroupBy(n => n.PersonId)
                     .AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(g => new NoteGrp
                      {
                          PersonID = g.Key,
                          Notes = string.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.NoteText))
                      });
```

If you can change `NoteGrp` you can add another property to holds all `NoteText` and join them at the other property:

```
var result = db.Notes.GroupBy(n => n.PersonId)
                     .Select(g => new NoteGrp
                      {
                          PersonID = g.Key,
                          Notes = g.Select(x => x.NoteText)
                      });

public class NoteGrp
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Notes { get; set; }
    ...

    public string Note
    { get { return string.Join(", ", Notes); } }
}
```