# Adding another table to a grouped linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the two tables

```
Person
__________
PersonID
PersonName
DOB
Status


Notes
__________
NoteID
PersonID
NoteText
Comments
LineNo
```

here is some sample content

```
 PersonID   PersonName    DOB          Status
   1    Mark Jacobs   07/07/1961    Active
```

and

```
NoteID  PersonID    NoteText    LineNo
 123       1        Line 1      1
 234       1        Line 2      2
 236       1        Line 3      3
```

So as an end result I want a Linq query to display something like that

```
PersonID    PersonName    DOB           Note
   1    Mark Jacobs   07/07/1961        Line 1, Line 2, Line 3
```

I have a working linq query for the Notes table, but would like to include some fields from Persons table as well:

```
 var result = (from n in db.Notes
                  group n.NoteText by n.PersonID into g
                  select new { 
                      PersonID = g.Key, 
                      Notes = g.ToList()
                  }).AsEnumerable() 
                 .Select(item => new NoteGroupDTO { 
                     PersonID = item.PersonID,
                     Notes = string.Join(", ", item.Notes)
                 }).ToList();
```

I'd like to add Person name, DOB, and Status to the select list.

I created a class

```
public class PersonNoteDTO
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

To my query I added a join and order by clause to order by line numbers. But I am not sure how to add fields to the select list in my anonymous object:

```
 var result = (from n in db.Notes
                  join p in db.Persons on n.PersonID=p.PersonID
                  orderby n.LineNo
                  group n.NoteText by n.PersonID into g
                  select new { 
                      PersonID = g.Key, 
                      Notes = g.ToList()
                  }).AsEnumerable() 
                 .Select(item => new PersonNoteDTO { 
                     PersonID = item.PersonID,
                     Notes = string.Join(", ", item.Notes)
                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by multiple fields and then access these properties through the `.Key` property:

```
var result = (from n in db.Notes
              join p in db.Persons on n.PersonID equals p.PersonID
              group new { n.NoteText, n.LineNo } by new { n.PersonID, n.PersonName, p.DOB, p.Status } into g
              select new { 
                  PersonID = g.Key.PersonID, 
                  PersonName = g.Key.PersonName, 
                  DOB = g.Key.DOB, 
                  Status = g.Key.Status, 
                  Notes = g.OrderBy(i => i.LineNo).Select(i=> i.NoteText)
              }).AsEnumerable()

             .Select(item => new PersonNoteDTO { 
                 PersonID = item.PersonID,
                 PersonName = item.PersonName,
                 DOB = item.DOB,
                 Status = item.Status,
                 Notes = string.Join(", ", item.Notes)
             }).ToList();
```

If all these properties are indeed part of the `Person` class then you can also just `GroupJoin`:

```
var result = (from p in db.Persons
              join n in db.Notes on p.PersonID equals n.PersonID into personNotes
              select new
              {
                  Person = p,
                  Notes = personNotes.OrderBy(pn => pn.LineNo).Select(pn => pn.NoteText)
              }).AsEnumerable()
             .Select(item => new PersonNoteDTO { 
                 PersonID = item.Person.PersonID,
                 PersonName = item.Person.PersonName,
                 DOB = item.Person.DOB,
                 Status = item.Person.Status,
                 Notes = string.Join(", ", item.Notes)
             }).ToList();
```

But I suggest that you look into Navigation Properties. Then you won't even need the join. Just have an `.Include`

Comment: and how about ordering by LineNo to ensure correct order of lines?

Comment: I got an error `Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: int PersonID, string PersonName, System.DateTime DOB, string Status>' to 'int'`

Comment: That is exactly what I did - I used the first example but it giving me the above error

Comment: Which part of it throws the exception? If you remove the second select does the first part work?

Comment: looks like the first example worked. How can I add orderby to order the records by LineNo to ensure the lines are in the correct order?

Comment: @ElenaDBA - Updated both parts of answer :)

Comment: @ElenaDBA - looking again at your tables/classes - I suggest going with the second option

Comment: How would I order by LineNo using second option? And also just curious why would second option be a better fit?

Comment: @ElenaDBA - So I've updated second one to already take care of the ordering. Reason that second one is better in my opinion is that what you actually want is to have a collection of all the notes of a person - and that is what group join gives you. in a normal "flat" join you have to afterwards also group by. I think the sql generated is quite the same but it is in less code :)

Comment: Second one gives me a strange compile  error `'PersonNoteDTO' is a type which is not valid in a given context`. It is strrange because the same class works fine in the first query...

Comment: @ElenaDBA - can you try now? I missed a `,` after the `Person = p`

Comment: No, I have got the before. It gave me that error with the comma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127375/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-elenadba).